# Shell script print some number of words after a specific word

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, command-line

I am new to shell scripting. I have a log file and I want to `grep` only "elapsed time" and print the numeric just after this.

Log looks like this -

```
Thread:MkdirSUProc workarea:92d70a0a8 cid_working_on:3164187 line:1085 clientIP:10.176.118.170:39575 elapsed time:649 ms additional_info:, Replication info:
stack:  fs/server/mapserver/create.cc:1085
        fs/server/mapserver/locks.cc:108 lkOwner:0x92c38c0a8
Thread:WriteFile workarea:9dbc7c538 cid_working_on:2402759 line:875 clientIP:10.176.118.170:0 elapsed time:17287 ms additional_info:, Replication info:  wa = 0x9dbc816c8
stack:  fs/server/mapserver/write/writev3.cc:875
```

Want output like -

```
649
17287
```

Whenever I am using `grep`, it's printing the whole line. Any help and direction would be appreciated.

Comment: try `grep "elapsed time" | cut -d ' ' -f 7 | cut -d ':' -f2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution:*** This could be done with-in a single `awk`, could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/elapsed time:[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART+13,RLENGTH-13)}' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Using field separators try:

```
awk -F'elapsed time:|ms' '$2{print $2}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
649
17287
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
grep -o 'elapsed time:[0-9]*' file | grep -o '[0-9]*'
```

Or if your `grep` supports Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE):

```
grep -Po 'elapsed time:\K[0-9]+' file
```

Comment: Won't work on BSD variant but I suppose as the question is tagged with linux, it's fine to do it like this.

Comment: Strange that BSD doesn't like the `*` if the pattern starts with a bracket expression. The first one works if you change the second `grep` to `grep -o '[0-9]\+'`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually `sed` is preferred for these tasks.

You may use:

```
sed -n 's/.* elapsed time:\([0-9]*\) ms.*/\1/p' file
```

```
649
17287
```